# Handling Nested Arrays/List in JSON return with fjsonparser in Vertica

Tags: python, sql, json, vertica

I'm running into an issue and I cannot find a good way to handle it.  I'll provide an example.

Say I'm making an API call to Amtrack using Python Requests to get information about their tickets.  The return is coming back in a JSON format like this:

```
{
   "tickets": [
    {
      "id":               12345,
      "external_id":      "abcdefg",
      "created_at":       "2015-04-27T22:55:29Z",
      "updated_at":       "2015-04-27T10:38:52Z",
      "type":             "commuter",
      "priority":         "high",
      "status":           "open",
      "recipient":        "Amanda",
      "requester_id":     1234567,
      "route_id":      1234567,
      "tags":             ["round-trip", "commuter"],
      "via": {
        "channel": "web"
      },
      "custom_fields": [
        {
          "id":    27642,
          "value": "Commuter Ticket"
        },
        {
          "id":    27648,
          "value": "reoccuring charge"
        }
      ],

    }
}
```

I am generating a JSON file with about 1,000,000 tickets.

I want to put this into a Vertica table, so I use the built in fjsonparser, and it goes great, except with the Custom_Fields key.  I can get it into a table, but the column is full of barely readable garbage that I can't even put into the text here.

I'm trying to figure a good way to handle this. I need the data inside the Custom_Fields, but because of the formatting, parsing it as a string is not feasible.  I considered adding all the custom fields to their own JSON file when I write to file after the API pull.  Something like:

```
CF_list = data['tickets']['custom_fields']

with open(filePath, mode='w') as F:
        json.dump(CF_list, F)
```

The problem here is that I will have no way of tying the Custom_Fields back  to the ticket they came from.  I'm needing some help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `flatten_arrays=true` to the `FJSONPARSER`. This will flatten the nested arrays.